# dispatch_async not execute everytime on Remote notification(APNs)

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, ipad, apple-push-notifications

Normally the below code is working fine but when I execute this code from remote notification(APNs) "queue2" not get execute, I am curious to know what I am missing in below code snippet.

```
//On didReceiveRemoteNotification, I am calling refresh method using singleton object
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[NetworkDispatcher sharedInterface] refresh];
}

//Created two queues, initialise in "NetworkDispatcher" init method
dispatch_queue_t queue1 = dispatch_queue_create("com.Test.NetworkDispatcher", NULL);
dispatch_queue_t queue2 = dispatch_queue_create("com.Test.NetworkDispatcher.PostRequests", NULL);
```

//and below is the "refresh" method in "NetworkDispatcher" class

```
- (void)refresh
{
    dispatch_async(queue1, ^{
           if ([self refreshWorker])
           {
               dispatch_async(queue2, ^{
                  [self syncAllParties];
              });
       }
       });
}
```

dispatch_async(queue2, gets hit but syncAllParties doesn't get called all the times
after some times when other post api has been called - this automatically starts getting executed
at that time all the request queued will get processed as if queue was locked and got unlocked by these POST operation

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The obvious answer is that `[self refreshWorker]` returns `NO`, so the code never reaches the second dispatch call. Have you checked its return value?

Comment: nope its returning yes, I checked using breakpoint.